# JNI library in Android Sometime Created in libs/armeabi sometims obj/armeabi?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How does build determine where to put .so files?  What is the default place it looks for loading them at runtime? libs/armeabi/so?  Is this configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the output directory of the library by adding the following line to Application.mk

```
NDK_APP_OUT := <output path>
```

Answer (score 2):

During build process shared library is created in obj/local/armeabi by linking bunch of object files and other libraries (static or shared).

After that strip command is run to strip out debugging symbols. It reads library in obj/local/armeabi directory and writes output in libs/armeabi directory. So final library, that is packaged in apk file is taken only from libs directory. "obj" directory is intermediate, it is not used in apk packaging process.